# PHP doesn't insert form data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got it all working, thanks for all your help and pointing me in the right direction.

i have a web host, which has MySQL, and phpMyAdmin. The code below shows the PHP in my .php file. When i submit the form, the data does not store in the SQL database.

My database is a table called 'Logins'. It has three fields: 'userID' which is an autoincrement type,'email' which is a VARCHAR, and 'password' which is also a VARCHAR.

I have tested my connection, and it does work, meaning something in the code is wrong, but i can't find it. I would be grateful if you guys could help me.

This is my code:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
              <p>Email Address:</p>
              <input type="text" name="email" required autofocus pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Please enter your email">
              <p>Password:</p>
              <input type="text" name="password" required placeholder="Enter your password">
              <p>Confirm Password:</p>
              <input type="text" name="confirmpassword" required placeholder="Confirm your password">
              <br>
              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Register">
            </form> 


            <?php
                if($_POST['submit']=="Submit")
                {
                    $email = cleanData($_POST['email']);
                    $password = cleanData($_POST['password']);
                    $message = "wrong answer";
                    addData($email, $pasword);
                }

                function cleanData($data){
                    $data = trim($data);
                    $data = stripslashes($data);
                    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                    $data = strip_tags($data);
                    return $data;
                }

                function addData ($email, $password)
                {
                    //include("dbinfo.php");
                    $dbhost = 'mysql11.000webhost.com';
                       $dbuser = '************'; //censored for security
                       $dbpass = '******'; //censored for security
                       $conn = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");

                       if(! $conn )
                       {
                          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                       }
                    $sql="INSERT INTO Logins ('userID','email','password') VALUES (null, '$email', '$password')";
                    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Does the Logins table allow the userID field have a null value in it?

Comment: userID is the primary key, and i have set it to autoincrement, so each time a new record is added, it increase it by 1. Therefore, there is no need to specify a userID

Comment: Then don't specify it.  Your code tries to insert a null value, instead of letting it default to the next autoincrement value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql insert field names should not be in quotes and you mentioned that `userID` is autoincrementing so no need to include it unless you want to set it to a specific value.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Logins (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";
```

You should also consider changing to `mysqli` since `mysql` is depreciated.

**Edit:** Your `mysql_connect` is missing the database select variable in the code you provided.

You will find debugging mysql queries much easier if you make use of the return values of each mysqli function. The below code checks for, and returns, any errors relating to database connection, query prepare, parameter binding, and execution.

This procedure makes it much easier to identify problems if they occur and with modification can be used to log errors, and report errors to the user even in production.

```
function addData ($email, $password)
{
    //include("dbinfo.php");
    $dbhost = 'mysql11.000webhost.com';
    $dbuser = '************'; //censored for security
    $dbpass = '******'; //censored for security
    $dbname = ''; // this is currently missing
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Connect failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    // define the query
    $sql="INSERT INTO Logins (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    // prepare the query
    if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        // failed to prepare query;
        die("Prepare failed: ".$stmt->error);
    }
    // bind the parameters
    if (!$res = $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password)) {
        // failed to bind
        die("Bind failed: ".$stmt->error);
    }
    // execute
    if (!$res = $stmt->execute()) {
        // failed to execute
        die("Execute failed: ".$stmt->error);
    }
    echo "Rows inserted: ".$stmt->affected_rows;
}
```

Comment: i tried removing the quotes but i got a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING' error

Comment: Check your code. There is no T_STRING error in the $sql line I posted.

Comment: Okay, i changed it, now theres no error, but the data is still not being stored in the SQL database

Comment: If you echo the `$sql` and copy paste into phpmyadmin does it work/error?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you instructed, so i just added: 'echo $sql;' without the quotes to the next line, and that didn't work, and gave no error

Comment: In your code `echo $sql;` after you define `$sql`, run it and copy the output sql query string. You mentioned in your question your host has phpMyAdmin so open it, go to sql tab and paste the string and run it. Does it work/error?

Comment: It says:

Inserted rows: 1
Inserted row id: 1 (Query took 0.0003 sec)

SQL query:
INSERT INTO Logins( email,
PASSWORD )
VALUES (
'$email', '$password'
)

Comment: No, you've just inserted `$email`, not the value of the variable, eg `test@test.com`. Did you copy the echoed sql query? Or the query from your php script?

Comment: where it says: Run SQL query/queries on database...i entered the code: INSERT INTO Logins (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')

Comment: No, you need to enter the echoed string generated by your php script. Eg `INSERT INTO Logins (email, password) VALUES ('the-email-entered@test.com', 'the-password-entered')` that includes the values entered in the form. This is to test the query generated by your php script.

Comment: my php script doesnt echo anything, i dont think so. The way i design it was to send the data to the sql database, then the action would be to go to another php page

Comment: So that you can debug the problem, `echo $sql;` after you define `$sql` and use it in phpmyadmin to identify whether your query is working. Once you have debugged the problem you can remove the echo.

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know how to do that, this is what i entered: 'INSERT INTO Logins (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')
echo $sql;'.......and it gave me this error: '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo $sql' at line 2 '

Comment: You can't follow my instructions on how to debug it. I'm sorry, I cannot help you

Comment: when you say echo £sql; after i define $sql. i can do that, but then how do i use it in phpmyadmin, as i dont think it will let me put in php variables in the sql tab

Answer (score 0):

change `if($_POST['submit']=="Submit")`

to `if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password']))`

Comment: You have to remove quotes from INSERT INTO query, like @Tristan said, also make sure that userID attribute allows null or is AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: i tried removing the quotes but i got a 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING' error

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

you must replace the line :if($_POST['submit']=="Submit")
By   `if(!empty($_POST['submit']))`
Or by `if($_POST['submit']=="Register")`

Try to connect with wrong password and wrong login want to know if
it display the message

Comment: Okay, i tried changing it on my test php file, and it echoed 'login successful' even though i entered wrong details, so now im thinking something could be wrong with my connection?